# Alternating group generators

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Consider the alternating group $\mathcal A_n$ ($n$ is an odd integer). Do $(12\cdots n)$ and $(12)(34)$ generate $\mathcal A_n$? In other words, $\langle (12\cdots n),(12)(34)\rangle =\mathcal A_n$.

I know that $\langle (12\cdots n),(123)\rangle=\mathcal A_n$. But how can we make $(123)$?

Comment: Hint:  Try conjugating $(1\;2)(3\;4)$ repeatedly by $(1\;2\;\cdots\;n)$.

Comment: It produces the permutation $(i\quad i+1)(i+2\quad i+3)$. I think it does not work. Could you explain more, please?

Comment: Following Jim's advice you get all of $(12)(34)$,$(34)(56)$, $(56)(78)$, $\ldots$, $(n-2\quad n-1)(n\quad 1)$. What can you do with those?

Comment: @Jim Belk that's not going to work. Conjugation is an automorphism so preserves order of elements.

Comment: I think producing a cycle of order 3 can be useful.

Comment: We have $(12)(34)$ and $(23)(45)$ in the group. also, we have $(1n)(23)$. However, $(12)(34)(23)(45)=(13542)$ and $(12)(34)(1n)(23)=(1342n)$ and $(13542)(1342n)=(14n)(352)$ which is of order 3.

Comment: It is too dificult to find an answer. I spent several hours finding an answer. It is written on a paper. So it must be true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collecting the bits from comments to an answer.

By conjugating $\sigma_1=(12)(34)$ by powers of $(123\cdots n)$ we get the permutations $\sigma_i=(i\ i+1)(i+2\ i+3)$, where we count modulo $n$, if some of the entries are $>n$. Then, using the assumption $2\nmid n$ we get
$$
\tau=\sigma_1\sigma_3\sigma_5\cdots\sigma_{n-2}=(12)(34)(34)(56)\cdots(n-2\ n-1)(n\ 1)=(12)(n1)=(1n2)
$$
after a mass cancellation. (I am interpreting the products in the order that the rightmost one is the first to be applied, if you use the other possible convention, then you get the inverse of this result).

So $\tau^{-1}=(n12)$. Conjugating this by $(123\cdots n)$ gives $(123)$ taking us to the point, where the OP can use the known result.

Comment: excellent! Thank you a lot Jyrki.